# Why do I get a 404, is it codeigniter routes issue?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am having an issue with CI routes. I keep getting a 404 even though my routes are defined.

I have these routes defined in my routes config file:

```
$route['s'] = "s";
$route['s/(:any)'] = "s/$1";
```

When I try to access `http://localhost/s/x4dB/stripe`, I get a 404. I put a few `echo` and `exit` statements in my controller and I noticed that it reaches my controller
up till the end of the constructor, after that it just throws a 404. I have the method index defined and it never reaches it.

Just to be clear, I have other routes setup and they are working correctly.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: did you try with `"s/index/$1";`

Comment: I haven't tried that but I will. Shouldn't `index` be the default method?

Comment: index is default but you have to mention in `route`

Comment: What is ``$config['base_url']`` in your project? I think in your case the ``s`` was interpreted as project name instead controller name.

Comment: @jonijones My base URL is set to `http://localhost/`. The controller named `s` is reached and the constructor is executed but it just doesn't reach `index`, so it is finding my controller. @kumar_v I will give this change a try soon when I am at my dev computer.

Comment: @kumar_v Can you add your comment as an answer with a little explanation in case it helps someone out in the future. It worked for me!

Comment: Do you still have your default route defined above the routes seen in your original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$route['s/(:any)'] = "s/index/$1";
```

As we discussed in comment, While calling the controller default constructor will execute and then index function will execute if no function name mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$route['s/(:any)'] = "s/$1";
$route['s'] = "s";
```